# Can $S^1$ act freely on $\mathbb{C}P^2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, covering-spaces, projective-space, cw-complexes

> Prove that $S^1$ cannot act freely on the complex projective space $\mathbb{C}P^2$.

I just learned some basic concept about homology group and covering space. But I have no clue how to prove this proposition. If the group action is also propely discontinuous, then we may relate the problem to the deck transformation about $\mathbb{C}P^2$, which I have no idea how to compute it.

I have known that $\mathbb{C}P^n$ can be regarded as
$$
S^{2n+1}\backslash\langle v\sim\lambda v\rangle, |\lambda|=1
$$
or
$$
D^{2n}\backslash\langle v\sim\lambda v\rangle, v\in\partial D^{2n},  |\lambda|=1.
$$

Appreciate any help!

Comment: I believe you can prove this by realizing that $X:=\mathbb{CP}^2/S^1$ must be a $3$-manifold, with a fibration $S^1\to \mathbb{CP}^2\to X$, so you can write down the Serre spectral sequence. You can calculate $H_0(X)=H_3(X)=\mathbb Z$ and $H_1(X)=H_2(X)=0$. But then the spectral sequence, which degenerates on the $E_2$-page, does not converge to what you want.

Comment: Alternatively, $\mathbb{CP}^2$ would be an orientable circle bundle over $X$, which is classified by $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)=0$. Thus $\mathbb{CP}^2\to X$ needs to be a trivial fibration, i.e., $\mathbb{CP}^2\cong X\times S^1$. But this is impossible by looking at the fundamental group.

Comment: Do you know the Lefschetz fixed point theorem?

Comment: @Eric Wonderful suggestion, but don’t we still need the cohomology structure?

Comment: Take infinitesmall action you'll get a nowhere zero vector field, then use Poincare Hopf Index Theorem. Note that it is a special case of Lefschetz, just for make things easier.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes. If the Lefschetz number of $f:X→X$
 is not zero, then $f$
 has fixed point. Would you like to write a detailed solution?

Comment: @TedShifrin you need the cohomology structure to say that *any* continuous map $\mathbb{C}P^2 \to \mathbb{C}P^2$ has a fixed point, but for homeomorphisms it's enough to consider the Lefschetz number mod $2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @Eric Wofsey's suggestion, we can prove that any homeomorphism of $\mathbb{C}P^2$ has a fixed point. This implies that no non-trivial group can act freely on $\mathbb{C}P^2$.

Suppose $f : \mathbb{C}P^2 \to \mathbb{C}P^2$ is a homoemorphism. Then on each $H_{2i}(\mathbb{C}P^2; \mathbb{Z})$, the induced map $f_*$ is multiplication by $\pm 1$. Therefore the Lefschetz number of $f$ is a sum of $3$ integers which are each $\pm 1$, in particular odd, in particular non-zero. So by the Lefschetz fixed point theorem, $f$ has a fixed point.